# How to find first 3 max values in a specified column?

Tags: r, max

In R, I tried several codings but they all got errors messages.  But even finally some turned out with the result, they do not look like correct.  Indeed they look a bit mess up.  Why?

I tried to find max values from the column of 'no. of ratings' for different smart water bottle products, but received 'volumes' column's descriptions.

```
> Smart_Water_Bottle_Review[which.max(Smart_Water_Bottle_Review$`no. of ratings`)]
# A tibble: 9 x 1
  `volumne (oz)`
  <chr>         
1 16            
2 17, 21        
3 20            
4 20.3          
......       
Warning message:
In which.max(Smart_Water_Bottle_Review$`no. of ratings`) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

And as I changed to another column, again, another column's result other then that showed up.

```
Smart_Water_Bottle_Review[which.max(Smart_Water_Bottle_Review$`volumne (oz)`)]
# A tibble: 9 x 1
  `keep hot (hrs)`
  <chr>           
1 NIL             
2 0               
3 NIL             
......          
Warning message:
In which.max(Smart_Water_Bottle_Review$`volumne (oz)`) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Simply speaking, I asked for the max value of no. of ratings, it gives the volumne; and asked for 'volumne', it gave 'keep hot'.
Plus, I asked for max, it provides everything.
Please advise how to correct these or the right syntax, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

It looks like you have your variables stored as character, rather than numeric. The `NAs introduced by coercion` warning is saying that the variable was converted to numeric, but that some values weren't number-like and couldn't be converted (e.g., the `NIL` value). You should convert your variable to numeric first with `as.numeric()` and verify that all values are correctly converted.

Second, when you subset a data frame or tibble with `[` using numbers and no commas, it selects the *column* matching that index.

Here is how I would recommend you solve this problem

```r
library(dplyr)
Smart_Water_Bottle_Review |>
  mutate(`no. of ratings` = as.numeric(`no. of ratings`)) |>
  filter(`no. of ratings` == max(`no. of ratings`, na.rm = TRUE))

# alternative, notice the comma indicating to use [row, column] indexing
Smart_Water_Bottle_Review[which.max(as.numeric(Smart_Water_Bottle_Review$`no. of ratings`)) , ]
```

You mentioned that you wanted the top 3 values. That is most easily done by sorting the data frame:

```r
library(dplyr)
Smart_Water_Bottle_Review |>
  mutate(`no. of ratings` = as.numeric(`no. of ratings`)) |>
  arrange(-`no. of ratings`) |>
  slice(3)
```

Comment: Actually, there was an initial problem about my conflicting dplyr file, which caused failure to arrange/filter function.  To resolve, I install.packages("conflicted") and library('conflicted), then it allows arrange.  But still it has a problem with some of my columns arrange function to work, while some others work well, although I already reformatted all into numeric in my csv file so to test.  So, for some columns like the amazon_rating with similar no. of digits, it worked well, whilst for the no_of_rating, I had to use the mutate & as. numeric functions as you suggested.  A bit puzzled!

Answer (score -1):

for no_of_rating:

```
smartrating %>% 
 mutate(no_of_ratings_100s = as.numeric(no_of_ratings_100s)) %>%
 arrange(-no_of_ratings_100s)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  Products                                               no_of_ratings_100s
  <chr>                                                               <dbl>
1 Hydrate Spark 3 Tracks (not insultaed)                              37.3 
2 Hydrate Spark Stainless Steel 21 oz                                 16.5 
3 CrazyCap Self Cleaning, UV water purifyer                           11.9 
4 Thermos 24 oz hydration bottle w smart lid                          11.5 
5 LARQ                                                                 8.29
6 Philips Water GoZero UV Self-Cleaning Vacuum Insulated               3.22
7 Bellabeat                                                            0.37
8 Equa Smart Water                                                     0.02
```

for amazon_rating: (no mutate function is needed)

```
smartamazon %>% 
  arrange(-amazon_ratings_5)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  Products                                               amazon_ratings_5
  <chr>                                                             <dbl>
1 LARQ                                                                4.5
2 CrazyCap Self Cleaning, UV water purifyer                           4.4
3 Hydrate Spark Stainless Steel 21 oz                                 4.4
4 Hydrate Spark 3 Tracks (not insultaed)                              4.4
5 Philips Water GoZero UV Self-Cleaning Vacuum Insulated              4.1
6 Equa Smart Water                                                    4  
7 Bellabeat                                                           3.8
8 Thermos 24 oz hydration bottle w smart lid                          3.7
```